# Is there a way to search a pdf for a particular keyword and display the value associated with that keyword?

Tags: python, ocr

Suppose I have been given a few keywords and those keywords are in a PDF file. Is there a way to extract the values associated with the keywords?

I tried the following-

I used pdfminer to read a PDF file and convert it into a text file. After this step, I was able to extract the table data (using area parameter present in the tabula  package), but how do I search for a value associated with the keyword? I have 2 issues here-

1. The table structure isn't being retained and meaningful data from table (in the PDF) isn't showing up in the right way in the text file. Some SO sources say table structure from PDF can't be retained. So is there a way to be able to read the tale contents in a meaningful way?
2. Because of problem 1, I am unable to extract a value that is associated with a keyword.

Some SO answers suggest using OCR, but how will it be possible read in values?
Some also suggested using a machine learning/deep learning algorithm which should figure out where the tables in a PDF are and extract the tables. But my question is, how do i extract values associated with keyword?

Example- Suppose my pdf reads- "hello, how are you. My height is 6 feet. Your height is 5 feet". And suppose the keyword is "height". I should be able to extract the digit "6 , 5" as output. This means, a keyword can be repeated more than once in a PDF and all the values associated with the keyword have to be extracted.

Comment: If you are looking for data inside table, then first step you have to do is extracting tables from pdf. For doing this check this tutorial http://stanford.edu/~mgorkove/cgi-bin/rpython_tutorials/Using_Python_to_Extract_Tables_From_PDFs.php it shows how to get data from tables inside .pdf and write it to .csv file

Answer (score 0):

Once you have converted/OCRed the PDF and got the text from it then may be you want to read each sentence in the text(may be using `split(".")`) and run through the sentences with "height" and search of digits using `regex` something like below. This is just a rather simple suggestion based on limited info in the question and you may have to use different and/or multiple such patterns in order to get satisfactory result.

```
patt = r"\d+"
if "height" in sentence:
    print(re.findall(patt, m_s))
```